# How to use Rules to auto populate field B with the value of field A after saving a new node or updating an existing one?

Tags: 7, rules

This must be easy, but I just can't figure it out ...

My scenario is like so:

- I have a content type with **field A** (`title_field` - text field) (that contains the title) and **field B** (`field_tagged_as` taxonomy reference).
- I need to auto populate **field B** with the value from **field A**, after saving a new node or updating an existing node.

Is there a way to do this using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Comment: Merci for the accept Horia! Next question? Eg about [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) ...!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pierre! Does this rule also applies after updating a node (i.e: using VBO)? I will import it today!

Comment: I'm about sure it does apply for that also. If not just clone the rule (after you imported it) and adapt the event to make it fit your needs. Or first add some relevant event and then remove the event included in the imported rule here. To make it also work for using it with VBO, create a similar Rules Component (same conditions/actions), which you then use as "the operation" to be performed via VBO (check some of my other answers about rules, which also talk about VBO)

Comment: Well, it doesn't seam to work in may case, unfortunately. If I go and edit the rule, I can see that the "value" in the action is not imported. If I edit the action, at the value section it says: _The new value to set for the specified data.
Taxonomy term identifiers

Specify a comma-separated list of identifiers of taxonomy term entities._
Could this rule not work because `field_tagged_as` is a taxonomy reference field?

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194945/how-do-i-access-the-first-value-of-a-multiple-value-text-field-using-replacement/194958#194958) and let me know if that helps?

Comment: I have looked bt it doesn't seam to help. The value for the action will only accept _Taxonomy term identifiers_. _node:title-field_ is rejected.

Comment: Let me go do some extra experiments in my own environment then. I'll add another comment after I'm finished (I expect somewhere later on today).

Comment: Thanks so much! To get a bigger picture of what I am trying to do, I want to tag the node with its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format) that does exactly what your question is about:

```
{ "rules_auto_populate_fields" : {
    "LABEL" : "Auto populate fields",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_presave" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "title_field" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_tagged_as" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-tagged-as" ],
          "value" : "[node:title-field]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice the "entity has field" conditions, for both fields. Those conditions will make the fields available in the Rules Action ... (so that you can reference field A and set the value of field B).

If you have the Rules UI enabled, and if the machine names of your fields are indeed "`title_field`" (for field A) and "`field_tagged_as`" (for field B), you should be able to just import this rule in your own site. If you're using other machine names, just adapt the machine names prior to importing this rule (and apply similar changes in the fields mentioned in the Rules Action).